# How to fix incorrect command line mail user name on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, user-account

On OSX `12.2.1` I am seeing a message that I have mail. But if I type `mail` I see the following:

```
mail: /var/mail/Chris: Permission denied
```

If I list the contents of `/var/mail/` I see

```
chris
```

i.e. all lower case of Chris.  If I do `id -un` I get

```
Chris
```

i.e. it starts with capital C.
How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the result of `ls -l /var/mail/?hris`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a standard installation of macOS, the file system is case-insensitive. This means that `/var/mail/Chris` and `/var/mail/chris` refers to the same file. As such there's nothing to fix in that regard.

However, you are left with the first error message stating that permission was denied accessing the file. You can elevate your privileges to super user by using the `sudo` command (assuming your account is able to do so), and then make sure your user has the necessary permissions for the file. Open `Terminal` and run commands like this:

```
sudo chown Chris /var/mail/chris
sudo chmod u+r /var/mail/chris
```

Now the `mail` command should succeed in reading the file. If it doesn't you could be running into privacy restrictions. You can fix that by opening `System Preferences`, click `, Security & Privacy`, select the `Privacy` tab, select `Full Disk Access` in the list on the left, and then add `Terminal` to the list on the right (and ensure it has a checkmark).